# proper JSON-encode of magento object (decimals/currency)

Tags: currency, json

I'm trying to process a Magento object with JSON. Using json_encode($order->getData()) or Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($order->getData()), I get output such as the following:

`{
    "entity_id": "1",
    "state": "complete",
    "status": "complete",
    "coupon_code": null,
    "protect_code": "30447e",
    "shipping_description": "U.S. Postal Service - First Class",
    "is_virtual": "0",
    "store_id": "1",
    "customer_id": null,
    "base_discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_discount_canceled": "0.0000",
    "base_discount_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "base_discount_refunded": null,
    "base_grand_total": "8.6500",
    "base_shipping_amount": "3.3000",
    "base_shipping_canceled": null,
    "base_shipping_invoiced": "3.3000",
    "base_shipping_refunded": null,
    "base_shipping_tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_shipping_tax_refunded": null,
    "base_subtotal": "5.3500",
    "base_subtotal_canceled": null,
    "base_subtotal_invoiced": "5.3500",
    "base_subtotal_refunded": null,
    "base_tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_tax_canceled": null,
    "base_tax_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "base_tax_refunded": null,
    "base_to_global_rate": "1.0000",
    "base_to_order_rate": "1.0000",
    "base_total_canceled": null,
    "base_total_invoiced": "8.6500",
    "base_total_invoiced_cost": null,
    "base_total_offline_refunded": "0.0000",
    "base_total_online_refunded": "0.0000",
    "base_total_paid": "8.6500",
    "base_total_qty_ordered": "0.0000",
    "base_total_refunded": "0.0000",
    "discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "discount_canceled": "0.0000",
    "discount_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "discount_refunded": null,
    "grand_total": "8.6500",
    "shipping_amount": "3.3000",
    "shipping_canceled": null,
    "shipping_invoiced": "3.3000",
    "shipping_refunded": null,
    "shipping_tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "shipping_tax_refunded": null,
    "store_to_base_rate": "1.0000",
    "store_to_order_rate": "1.0000",
    "subtotal": "5.3500",
    "subtotal_canceled": null,
    "subtotal_invoiced": "5.3500",
    "subtotal_refunded": null,
    "tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "tax_canceled": null,
    "tax_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "tax_refunded": null,
    "total_canceled": null,
    "total_invoiced": "8.6500",
    "total_offline_refunded": "0.0000",
    "total_online_refunded": "0.0000",
    "total_paid": "8.6500",
    "total_qty_ordered": "1.0000",
    "total_refunded": "0.0000",
    "can_ship_partially": null,
    "can_ship_partially_item": null,
    "customer_is_guest": "1",
    "customer_note_notify": "1",
    "billing_address_id": "1",
    "customer_group_id": "0",
    "edit_increment": null,
    "email_sent": "1",
    "forced_shipment_with_invoice": null,
    "gift_message_id": null,
    "payment_auth_expiration": null,
    "paypal_ipn_customer_notified": null,
    "quote_address_id": null,
    "quote_id": "8",
    "shipping_address_id": "2",
    "adjustment_negative": null,
    "adjustment_positive": null,
    "base_adjustment_negative": null,
    "base_adjustment_positive": null,
    "base_shipping_discount_amount": null,
    "base_subtotal_incl_tax": null,
    "base_total_due": null,
    "payment_authorization_amount": null,
    "shipping_discount_amount": null,
    "subtotal_incl_tax": null,
    "total_due": null,
    "weight": "0.2200",
    "customer_dob": null,
    "increment_id": "100000002",
    "applied_rule_ids": "",
    "base_currency_code": "USD",
    "customer_email": "user@email.com",
    "customer_firstname": null,
    "customer_lastname": null,
    "customer_middlename": null,
    "customer_prefix": null,
    "customer_suffix": null,
    "customer_taxvat": null,
    "discount_description": null,
    "ext_customer_id": null,
    "ext_order_id": null,
    "global_currency_code": "USD",
    "hold_before_state": null,
    "hold_before_status": null,
    "order_currency_code": "USD",
    "original_increment_id": null,
    "relation_child_id": null,
    "relation_child_real_id": null,
    "relation_parent_id": null,
    "relation_parent_real_id": null,
    "remote_ip": "63.230.211.89",
    "shipping_method": "tablerate_bestway",
    "store_currency_code": "USD",
    "store_name": "Main Website\nStore\nDefault Store View",
    "x_forwarded_for": null,
    "customer_note": null,
    "created_at": "2009-05-15 23:14:53",
    "updated_at": "2009-05-16 15:01:29",
    "total_item_count": "1",
    "customer_gender": null,
    "base_custbalance_amount": null,
    "custbalance_amount": null,
    "is_multi_payment": null,
    "hidden_tax_amount": null,
    "base_hidden_tax_amount": null,
    "shipping_hidden_tax_amount": null,
    "base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt": null,
    "hidden_tax_invoiced": null,
    "base_hidden_tax_invoiced": null,
    "hidden_tax_refunded": null,
    "base_hidden_tax_refunded": null,
    "shipping_incl_tax": null,
    "base_shipping_incl_tax": null,
    "coupon_rule_name": null,
    "auctaneapi_discounts": null,
    "payment_authorization_expiration": null,
    "forced_do_shipment_with_invoice": null,
    "base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount": null
}`

Note how integers, decimals and currency are quoted. This isn't proper JSON-formatting as it processes as a string rather than a number. Anyone know how to modify this either with custom options or a special function that converts these to non-quoted numbers instead of strings?

Answer (score 2):

From PHP 5.3.3 on there is a JSON constant `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`that you can use when calling `json_encode()`:

```
json_encode($order->getData(), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );
```

I saw that there can also be `$options` passed to `Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($order->getData(), $cycleCheck, $options);` but from `Zend_Json` it seems this is only used for `enableJsonExprFinder` as option (`$options['enableJsonExprFinder']`) so I think going with the plain `json_encode` function is better in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about using this but wanted compatibility with PHP 5.2 if possible :(

Comment: Uh 5.2 compatibility... Well, then :)

Answer (score 2):

wound up using this... does the trick as a helper preprocessor that then calls core jsonEncode without needing php 5.3.

```
foreach($o->getData() as $k=>$v ){ 
  if (is_numeric($v)){ 
    $o->setData($k,(float)$v); 
   } 
}
```